# Canvas JS graph not working with large and small data

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

I am trying to built **doughnut chart** but, it's not working with this data:

```
    {  y: 12749, legendText:"PS 3", indexLabel: "PlayStation 3" },
    {  y: 103, legendText:"Wii", indexLabel: "Wii" },
    {  y: 1, legendText:"360",exploded: true, indexLabel: "Xbox 360" }, 
    {  y: 30, legendText:"DS" , indexLabel: "Nintendo DS"},
```

However, it is working fine with this:

```
    {  y: 129, legendText:"PS 3", indexLabel: "PlayStation 3" },
    {  y: 103, legendText:"Wii", indexLabel: "Wii" },
    {  y: 100, legendText:"360",exploded: true, indexLabel: "Xbox 360" }, 
    {  y: 30, legendText:"DS" , indexLabel: "Nintendo DS"},
```

Any suggestions for this problem, I know in google charts we can use logscale but I am not sure about this one.

Comment: How do you mean, not working? No chart? Console errors?

Comment: when i put the small and large data, no chart appear but when i put normal data i got the chart

Comment: no, i think it is just the data problem

Comment: Seems like a bug in their implementation? If you play with the demo on their own page: http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-types/html5-doughnut-chart/ and change the top value to `100`, then it breaks just as you describe

Comment: So, anything can be done to solve this issue??

Comment: I'd try a different charting library, maybe chart.js

Comment: Thanks for Your time

Answer (score 0):

I was able to track down what I think is the issue in canvasjs.min.js and fix it. Looks like an argument was missing from one of their functions. This can be fixed with a simple find and replace within canvasja.min.js. Search `function g(a,b)` and replace it with `function g(a,b,recursionCount)`. I was able to get your data working with this change.